# Add class and change css dynamically (jquery)

Tags: jquery, css, json

I'm working on a project where I'm parsing a json file to get the contents then do $.post using php to update changes. I'm able to read and write without any issues.

However, after I parse the data from json, I if I make any changes like adding a new class via click it adds the class but doesn't apply the css.

Ex:

```
    <div id="someID">lorem ipsum</div> <!-- (assuming I am "appending" this div via jquery and if I clicked on this div)

    <!-- it will become -->
    <div id="someID" class="red">lorem ipsum</div> <!-- the text and/or background should be red -->
```

I think I can apply a style="color: red" instead of applying class but I don't want that.

Any suggestions on how I can make this dynamic/live? Thanks.

Comment: I think the key thing is appending content to the body.

Comment: What makes you think the class is added if the style doesn't update?  Can you create a working demo in http://jsfiddle.com?

Comment: Can you add your CSS to the example?

Comment: I've made a logical error, it's all set now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Class will work fine using `.addClass`.

Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/TeHtz/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#someID").addClass("class_name_you_want_to_add");
```

for further reference you may want to look at http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#someID').addClass("red")
```

Try that